# What is actually request type 'HEAD' in ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, head

In my code, I have got request type `HEAD` but I actually don't know details about it. The code is like this:

```
function fileExists(pUrl)
{
    let fileExist = false;

    $.ajax({
        url:pUrl,
        type:'HEAD',
        async:false,
        success: function()
        {
            //file exists
            fileExist = true;
        },
        error: function()
        {
            //file not exists
            fileExist = false;
        }
    });

    return fileExist;
}
```

Can anybody tell me about the `HEAD`? thanks in advance

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `HEAD` HTTP request type is similar to `GET`, but only returns the header part of the result.

In your code, it will get back the response's HTTP status code, but won't download the file itself.

See the docs at  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD)